# Getting nth level children using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following situation. I want to access all **"nth"** children using jquery.

```html
<div id="root">
    <div id="block">
       <div>level 1
           <div>level 2</div>
           <div>level 3
               <div>level 3.1</div>
               <div>level 3.2</div>
           </div>
           <div>level 4
               <div>level 4.1
                   <div>level 4.1.1</div>
               </div>
               <div>level 4.2</div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div>level 1
           <div>level 2
               <div>level 3
                   <div>level 3.1</div>
               </div>
               <div>level 4</div>
           </div>
           <div>level 5</div>
       </div>
       <div>level 1
           <div>level 2</div>
           <div>level 3
               <div>level 3.1</div>
               <div>level 3.2</div>
           </div>
           <div>level 4
               <div>level 4.1</div>
               <div>level 4.2</div>
           </div>
           <div>level 5</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have _div = $("").appendTo( "#root" );
Now I want to access _nth level children through it. _nth may be-> 2/3/4
For example: I want to access 3rd level children of _div i.e. level 3.1,level 3.2 etc. How can I access it?
Please help.

Comment: Do you have full control over the HTML? If you do, you can do yourself a favor and give each level a class. `<div class="level-one">`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#root div:nth-child(2)" )
```

Will give you

```
<div>level 3
   <div>level 3.1</div>
   <div>level 3.2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you may need to look at your HTML structure, as I don't think it is giving you what you expect it to.

That being said, I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fu22huo/) for you to play with and modify as needed. I added some CSS to organize it a bit visually.

Essentially your code would either look something like this to grab everything in the nth-child:

```
var blockChild = 2;
$("#block div").find(":nth-child(" + blockChild + ")").css( "background-color", "yellow" );
```

I don't think that's what you want, so simply adding a .children() within the jQuery gets everything within that selected nth-child (IE the 3.1 AND 3.2 you referenced above but not the level 3 "heading")

```
var blockChild = 2;
$("#block div").find(":nth-child(" + blockChild + ")").children().css( "color", "red" );
```

You don't need to use the variable, and could hard code the nth-child, but it sounded like you may want to dynamically change it.

That being said, the nesting of your divs is a bit inconsistent. You nest level 3 & 4 into level 2 in the second block, but not the first or last. Maybe that was just a copy & paste error. I'd be happy to help further if this isn't working as intended.

Hope this helps!